# How to change jcheckbox "tick mark color or check box color" in Swing

Tags: java, swing

I need change only tick mark color or check box color in Swing's JCheckBox.

I am using NetBeans as my IDE, but I can only change whole checkbox with label background color. But my requirement only change the tick mark color.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO! When asking questions, please refer to [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), this will be a lot easier to answer if we can see your __relevant__ code.

Comment: Color of check icon is defined by the Look-and-Feel. So there is no common setting that allow you to modify it. The only thing that you can do is to paint this checked/unchecked icon by yourself and install it, using the methods setIcon/setSelectedIcon